# How do I use git without having a proper git server?

Tags: git, backup, git-remote, backup-strategies

I want to be able to make backups of my project in a windows environment without having to manually copy and paste my whole folder. Unfortunately I am not allowed to use a remote git server for this project, so I was wondering if I could use git for backing up my project on a mounted hard drive.

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976459/push-git-project-to-local-directory):

```
git remote add Y file:///path/to/Y
```

However, when I try to push I receive this error:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried to init a bare repository on my mounted device and local directory but I faced the same error.

Summarizing, I want to be able to backup my project in a windows environment automatically or with few commands such as git commit and git push. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did and what as far as I know works:

First you create a git repo:

```
cd e:/tmp 
mkdir backup
cd backup
git --bare init
```

Now the git repository was created you need to go to your files.

Let's say you use xampp and you want a backup from one of your projects.

```
cd e:/xampp/htdocs/project
git init
git add .
git remote add backup e:/tmp/backup
git commit -m "First commit"
git push backup master
```

Boom now it saved everything into your backup into master branch ;)
You can even do it in different HDs... that's how I keep code tracked at home 4 free into my backup HD.

Hope this help someone else in future as well.

See ya! ;)

Comment: Another one " git push --set-upstream backup master"

Answer (score 0):

you are almost right, just remove the "file:" in your route:

```
git remote add Y /path/to/Y
```

and everything should work fine.
If it doesnt work you should try this workaround,

enter this inside your removable hard disk drive:

```
git clone /path/to/your/project
```

then whenever you want to make a backup just enter a git pull inside your removable hard drive project folder. 
Any of this solutions should work for you

Comment: The second one I received this N:\my\remote\path>git clone "C$\my\local\path"
fatal: repository 'C$\my\local\path' does not exist

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your routes. Are you using git bash for windows or default cmd?

Comment: I am using default cmd

Comment: I recommend you to use git bash because instructions will work no matter wich OS you use, it is included when you install git for windows. I don't have much expirience with windows cmd so can't help you with that